# This is my MySQL query, how to write in CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

This is my MySQL query and how to write it in CodeIgniter

```
SELECT distinct a.user_name
FROM wl_customers a
    INNER JOIN tbl_bid b ON a.customers_id = b.customers_id
    INNER JOIN tbl_portfolio c ON b.portfolio_id=c.portfolio_id 
WHERE c.portfolio_id='16'
```

Comment: did you try below answer.

Comment: The CodeIgniter documentation is very comprehensive. Please read the documentation. https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/examples.html

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! To give you a great answer, it might help us if you have a glance at [ask] if you haven't already. It might be also useful if you could provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

Try like this.Use join between tables.

```
<?php

$query = $this->db->distinct()
        ->select('a.user_name')
        ->from('wl_customers as a'); 
        ->join('tbl_bid as b','a.customers_id=b.customers_id');
        ->join('tbl_portfolio as c','b.portfolio_id=c.portfolio_id')
        ->where('c.portfolio_id',16)
        ->get();
print_r($query->result_array);//array of your records
```

for more read docs https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html

Comment: Please don't make him feel lazy because of your codes given to him. Let him try first and then you shall help him

Comment: hope he will learn something from here.and do best next time.

Comment: Ya that is good moto. But atleast if he is a child we cam make him walk but as of now he has not tried anything in CI. That is the reason i have told you. Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

using active records

```
    $this->db->select('distinct a.user_name');
    $this->db->from('wl_customers as a'); 
    $this->db->join('tbl_bid as b','a.customers_id=b.customers_id');
    $this->db->join('tbl_portfolio as c','b.portfolio_id=c.portfolio_id');
    $this->db->where('c.portfolio_id',16,false);
    $query = $this->db->get();
```

Answer (score -2):

```
$query = $this->db->query("
SELECT MAX(A.BID),B.* FROM tbl_bid A INNER JOIN wl_customers B ON A.customers_id=B.customers_id
WHERE portfolio_id='16'
");
```

Comment: This is very cumbersome, you should make use of the Query Builder class and follow @Rohan's advice and read the documentation.

Comment: CI doesn't force you to use the query builder esp. if you already have working sql.